# Python buffer audio with low latency

Tags: python, audio, streaming

Is there a way to achieve low latency audio playback in python? Both sounddevice and pyaudio have latencies >0.5 seconds. pygame is >0.3 seconds with significant choppiness. Im streaming audio so I need latencies in the milliseconds or at least < 0.05 seconds.

Is my implementation faulty or should I be using a different library.

```
import sounddevice as sd
a = sd.RawOutputStream(samplerate = RATE, blocksize = CHUNK*4, channels = 1, dtype="int32", latency = 0)
a.start()
a.write(buffer)
```

Comment: You should try different devices from your device list. The latency will very much depend on the audio back-end (a.k.a. host API). If you are using Windows, you should try ASIO and/or WASAPI "exclusive" mode for minimal latency.

Comment: @Matthias Would there only be one audio output device if there are no audio peripherals setup (aside from a built in speaker)? Also can you point me to any libraries/docs for using the mac counterpart, coreaudio.

Comment: On macOS/CoreAudio you can try the `change_device_parameters` setting (see https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.1/api/platform-specific-settings.html#sounddevice.CoreAudioSettings), but I have no experience with that, it may not change anything. More importantly, I've just seen that you specify an explicit `blocksize`. For low latencies it might be better to use `blocksize=0` (which is the default) and `latency='low'`. I assume you are not including the time for starting the stream in your latency measurements?

Comment: `latency='low'` seems to work well but `blocksize=0` wouldn't make sense if you have a defined blocksize from the audio stream producer.